# different declaration of a static variable

Tags: c#, variables, global-variables

is it possible (in C#) to have different declarations of a static variable?
e.g.
I have a "static bool test = true".
Now I want a "static int interval" but it should depend on the test.

```
if (test)
{
    static int interval = 1;
}
else
{
    static int interval = 5;
}
```

because all variables aren't in methods and directly declared in a class I cant use any of this as it is...

thanks in advance!

Comment: `static int interval = (test ? 1 : 5)`

Comment: Do you want to change value of interval variable inside any function or at a class level?

Comment: 1: Your code snippet shows two variables, which are both invisible outside the snippet. 2. Perhaps you mistake `static` for `const`? BTW, @Sean's hint works for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pretty similar ways to achieve that:

1. use the ternary within your assignement:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       static bool test = true;
       static int interval = (test ? 1 : 5)
   }
   ```
2. use a static constructor:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       static bool test = true;
       static int interval;
       static MyClass()
       {
           if(test) interval = 1;
           else interval = 5;
       }
   }
   ```